# How to check when a video loops html5

Tags: javascript

I can usualy check for the end of a video with the 'ended' event. but this is not fired when the video is on loop. I have also tried to compare currentTime and duration - but currentTime is not always correct to the exact second. What methods are available to detect the video has restarted?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `eventListener` for the `seeked` event and then check that, since a video that is being looped will automatically 'seek' the start of the video. If you then check that the start is 0, then it's (probably) not the user who reset it so its an automatic seek event. Either way, even if the user has put it back to zero it technically counts as a  loop I think.

You could technically also check if the user clicked and if they did, you know its not an automatic loop, otherwise if its not a `click` and the `currentTime` is set to 0, its a loop.

It will work like the following:

### HTML

```
<video id="video" loop autoplay>
    <source src="video.mp4" />
</video>
```

### Javascript

```
document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("seeked", function(event){
    if(document.getElementById("video").currentTime === 0){
        // do what you want to do on relax
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `timeupate` event of the video. Then store the `currentTime` and check if the current duration is smaller then the last saved duration. If this happens, the video has restarted.
See this fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/z7Lueq63/

Comment: This fails when the user clicks on the controls (ie. if I first click halfway through the video, then one-quarter through it will be reported as a loop even though it wasn't.). Also, its time**d**ate, typo :).